# Could two-wheel tractors be used in place of automobiles?

Tags: technology, vehicles

[Two wheel tractors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-wheel_tractor) are a smaller type of tractor, which, as the name implies, only have a single axle with two wheels. Is it plausible that these machines could draw passenger cars and be used as the main method of travel, taking the place that buses or cars take in reality? It seems, at least to me, that two-wheel tractors might be made to draw horse-drawn vehicles, which could make them more attractive than automobiles.

Comment: The answer is in [the wiki article you included in the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-wheel_tractor#Philippines).

Comment: Sure, as long as you don't mind a ride that is less comfortable, less safe, and slower than using a proper automobile chassis.

Comment: your biggest problem is the articulation joint, it is a pretty serious weak point  that needs a lot of reinforcement as weight increases. also you end up with a terrible turning radius but then so did early cars.

Comment: Once you get to speeds faster than crawling, there will be serious problems with steering and braking. Those problems can be solved, but the solution would be more complex that building 4-wheeled (or at least 3) vehicles straight away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, and we have them today... buses, semi-tractor/trailers, etc.**

The only difference between a two-wheeled tractor and a bus is that the shell and frame of the bus are contiguously connected. But we need only look at [articulated buses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articulated_bus) to see examples that demonstrate the plausibility of using a single-axle tractor to move [chains of things around](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tG8wYlIOqbI).

**Those buses have two axles on the tractor, dude...**

Yup, they do. The buses serve no purpose other than basic "proof of concept," but they also underscore the fact that no one uses only a single-axle tractor for on-road applications, and these weaknesses are important.

Articulation has advantages and disadvantages. It's obvious advantage is to chain a very long length of compartments for transport. A train is nothing more than a complex form of your two-wheel tractor. And in the Australian outback, very long chains of trailers are connected to a single semi-tractor.

A single-axle tractor would be cheap, which is why it was used in farming applications — but you almost never (if ever, I didn't do the research) see them used today. Why?

Because their disadvantages are enormous. Articulation comes with a loss of control, especially where weight is concerned. You need only watch a triple-semi driving down the road with a light wind to see what I mean. That loss of control is ameliorated by adding axles to the tractor for stability.

And it's worth noting that a horse can't be efficiently equated with a two-wheeled tractor. Horses have "two axles." They're also the driver. Oh, there's a human directing them, but the human is very much the *back seat driver.* The horse is executing and controlling the motion. The equivalent with a single-axle service would be for the driver to be sitting on that front axle, or to have an enormously complex control structure that spanned the articulation. But where there's complexity, there's inevitably the effort to simplify for economic reasons.

**Conclusion**

I'm in agreement with @o.m. that two-wheeled tractors are a cheap-and-easy method of converting from horse-and-buggy to horsless carriages, but just as the buggy shifted from one axle to two for any weight-carrying purpose, your two-wheeled tractors would quickly get welded into two-axle configurations fairly quickly.

**With one plausible exception**

Driverless buses. So long as you don't need a human turning the wheel and stepping on the brake, you could plausibly see a single-axle tractor hauling passenger compartments around.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128036/discussion-on-answer-by-jbh-could-two-wheel-tractors-be-used-in-place-of-automob).

Answer (score 3):

**Not really.**

Yes, these vehicles *could* be used to replace passenger cars, if two-wheeled tractors and passenger wagons were available and cars were not. But it appears unlikely that an economy which can build both two-wheeled tractors and passenger wagons would be unable to build four-wheeled cars and buses, and they're just more convenient to use. Modern cars put the driver into an enclosed compartment with the passengers.

- Driver and passengers are protected from wind and rain. They can communicate easily.
- Driver and passengers can be protected from accidents by seatbelts, airbags, and crumple zones.
- Air resistance will be *much* lower, leading to better fuel efficiency for the same weight. (Sure, one can build big and gas-guzzling cars, but one doesn't have to.)
- I haven't driven one of those contraptions myself, but if a car with trailer is any indication they would be more difficult to handle.

Since we're on Worldbuilding, one might imagine an interstellar colony to a shirt-sleeves world where the colonists get plenty of those tractors and nothing else (to simplify spare parts). But once they build vehicles locally, I'd expect four wheels.

Comment: That said, I could imagine fully-enclosed passenger "cars" that have no drive train. Instead, you have two-wheel tractors that are either fully automated, or controlled entirely via electronic linkage. This might actually be a better alternative to purely communal vehicles. But this is something I could see happening in *our* world, after we've already passed through the "traditional automobiles" phase.

Comment: @Matthew wouldn't that just be a front wheel drive car?

Comment: @John, once *assembled*, yes, but imagine if the only things on your car that needed maintenance were the rear wheels/tires/brakes and wiper fluid (and very, very rarely, taillights). Batteries low on charge? Swapping to a new, fully charged tractor takes minutes. Dead battery pack? Steering out of alignment? Wheel bearings shot? Doesn't happen; maintaining the tractors is Somebody Else's Problem. Flat (front) tire? Swap the tractor.

Comment: @Matthew all that is true of a car if you have a mechanic, also consider swapping a car battery takes seconds, but how many people keep spare batteries around, keeping a spare tractor is an even bigger investment.

Comment: @John, you misunderstand; tractors are *communal*. They are maintained by, say, the Department of Transportation. You don't own them, so if the one you're using breaks, you're just given a new one from the pool. Also, you still have to take your vehicle to a mechanic and either rent something or do without while it's being serviced. With communal tractors, you never notice this happening. As for batteries, I'm not talking about piddling little 12Vs that we know how to swap. I'm talking about *electric vehicle* battery banks. We don't know how to swap those in "seconds", yet.

Comment: @Matthew because communal tractors have far lower usages and fewer numbers than cars, I would like to see how communal cars is supposed to work. also communal ownership and all electric are the kinds of things you should include in your answer no assume other people presume about someone elses answer. .

Comment: @John, both points *were* implied in my original comment. Anyway, there are *more* advantages (maintenance-wise) if the tractors use ICEs; I just don't expect that to ever happen. Also, I'm using "tractor" in the "piece of machinery that pulls something" sense. I don't want a communal *car* because who knows what's been done in there by other people... and I can't leave anything in it, ever... but if I owned just the passenger compartment, that's *much* more palatable. (Yeah, I don't buy *used* cars from non-family, either.)

Answer (score 3):

Though not exactly for passenger transportation, they already exist.

As a kid the farm where I spent my summers had a two wheeled tractor similar to the one in the picture, which standalone could be used for working the soil, with the tender attached could be used to transport a load, with the load sometimes being kids looking for some fun.

[image]

From there to equip the tender with some seats and then a cover the step is very short, and could make sense when you want to decouple the load/unload of passengers from the operation of the tractor. For example imagine all the passengers have to go through border control and the tractor has to depart for another trip: it is easier to detach if from the tender and use it on another one.

Just add passengers!

[image: http://baoquangngai.vn/channel/2025/201403/khong-keo-dai-thoi-gian-ho-tro-thay-the-xe-cong-nong-xe-3-banh-2299703/]

Comment: the more advanced version of those would be the Goldoni or Pierre compact tractors, http://www.pierretra.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=79&Itemid=685&lang=en which need an normal car like steering in the front to have a usable turning radius.